# Detect element tag name by its class

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there is a way to get the name of a element by its class or id.

for exemple `<input class="some-class" type="text" />` returns "input"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tagName` :

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("some-class")[0];
alert(input.tagName);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PG656/1/

Comment: @FabienPapet , great! if you need it in lower case , check it: http://jsfiddle.net/PG656/2/

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("some-class")[0]
alert(input.type);
alert(input.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$('.classTag').get(0).tagName;
```

or this:

```
$('.classTag')[0].tagName;
```

for ex we have this markup:

```
<div class=classTag>my div </div>


var $tag = $('.classTag')[0].tagName; //this will return 'DIV'as result
alert($tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tagName = $('.some-class').prop('tagName');
```

the name of the tag will be returned in capital letters

Answer (score 0):

Actually `$('.some-class')` returns an array of elements with this class, so you have to loop through it:

```
$('.some-class').each(function(){ 
    console.log(this.nodeName); 
});
```

this will output their node names to console